# How to get dom events like onClick and onChange to work when serving a tsx file with Bun.serve() and no framework

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, bun, react-dom-server

I'm trying to use [Bun](https://bun.sh/) and it's optimized built-in React library, without a framework, to build a simple one-page form application. I found work-arounds for dealing with icons and css, but ran into trouble getting `onInput` events to fire. I'm new to React, so decided to see if I could get a simple `onClick` example to work from [Quick Start - React -> Updating The Screen](https://react.dev/learn#updating-the-screen).

I already had bun installed, of course. I setup the project on Arch Linux with these commands:

```
% mkdir reactTryingStuff
% cd reactTryingStuff
% bun init
% bun add react react-dom
% bun add @types/react-dom -d
% mv index.ts index.tsx
```

I edited `package.json` to add a start script:

```
{
  "name": "reacttryingstuff",
  "module": "index.tsx",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "bun --watch run index.tsx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.8",
    "bun-types": "latest"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I edited index.tsx to setup the server:

```
import { renderToReadableStream } from "react-dom/server";
import MyApp from "./App";

const server = Bun.serve({
  port: 2000,
  async fetch(req) {
    const url = new URL(req.url);

    // render App.tsx for root path
    if (url.pathname === "/") {
      const stream = await renderToReadableStream(<MyApp />);
      return new Response(stream, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html" },
      });

    }

    return new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
  },
});

console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${server.port}`);
```

I copied App.js from [Quick Start - React -> Updating The Screen](https://react.dev/learn#updating-the-screen) and put it in file called App.tsx because I'm trying to learn typescript as well and also wanted it to show any errors right away.

App.tsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counters that update separately</h1>
      <MyButton />
      <MyButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function MyButton() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Clicked {count} times
    </button>
  );
}
```

Then I started the server:

`bun start`

It looked as expected, but the buttons do nothing when clicked. I've determined that the `onClick` event never fires.

Is there anyway to serve this example starting with `bun init` (and no other framework) that will be able to use DOM events like `onClick`?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that without using clientside javascript. You'll still need to use react-dom there to run your `MyApp` code with its state and click handling in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way to implement the example suggested in [Quick Start - React -> Updating The Screen](https://react.dev/learn#updating-the-screen). After setting up the project the same as in my question, `App.tsx` can stay as it was (which was directly copied from the Quick Start link). However, `index.tsx` needs to be completely different:

`index.tsx`

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import MyApp from "./App";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<MyApp />)
```

I get a typescript error in my editor about not finding 'document', but everything works anyway. The next step is to build the application:

`% bun build ./index.tsx --outdir ./MyApp`

That will create `./MyApp/index.js`. Now create the following `./MyApp/index.html`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, serve `MyApp` with:

`% bunx serve MyApp`

Everything works the same as at [Quick Start - React -> Updating The Screen](https://react.dev/learn#updating-the-screen).

The information about how to do a client-side server with bun isn't easy to find for a noob like me. The method that worked came from Bun's documentation on [Bun.build](https://bun.sh/docs/bundler).

Comment: There's something wrong with bun build or bunx because when I tried something similar on my own app, bunx returned "error: could not determine executable to run for package server". I tried removing things from the app to get it to work, but it kept giving the same error. Then I went back to this "MyApp" example, added some other stuff, and it didn't work. Then I removed the extra stuff so it was back to what's showing here, and it still gave the same error. Even starting over with a new directory gave the same error.

Comment: I tried again in yet another directory, this time starting with the example in Bun's documentation [Bun.build](https://bun.sh/docs/bundler). It worked. I added this example, and it continued to work. I added part of my app, and it still works. I'm not sure what triggered the error before or what I did to correct it.

Comment: Once I trigger the bunx server error "error: could not determine executable to run for package server", it keeps saying that even on builds that worked in other directories. I will file a bug.

Comment: I finally realized what's going on. My instructions above include a typo. It's `bunx serve MyApp` not `bunx sever MyApp` or `bunx server MyApp`. I will fix my answer.